# Visual Studio Community 2017 Freezes U-SQL script

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-data-lake

When submitting U-SQL scripts to ADLA Visual Studio freezes for a few seconds, and is constantly spiking for about 1-2 sec for all changes in the editor.

VS works fine with all other languages than U-SQL for me.

Similiar unsolved case: [Msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5787a2b5-0cc0-4b26-b906-9ca9b0617bcc/visual-studio-usql-editor-freeze-periodically?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Version: VS community 2017 15.6.7
Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio - 2.3.4000.6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are describing when you say "freezes" and "spiking", so my apologies in advance if this is not helpful. Two scenarios come to mind:

1) When you submit a U-SQL script to a Data Lake for execution, there is a period where Visual Studio is preparing the job. If you look in the Output Window you should see the activity. This can sometimes take a few minutes and appear as though nothing is happening, but it is actually quite busy.

2) There is a bug in VS tooling that causes code editing delays and "freezing" while editing U-SQL scripts. This specifically happens when the "ADLA Account" drop down references a remote account. If you change it to "(Local-machine)" while editing, the problem should go away (just don't forget to change it to the correct account before you submit the job).

If neither of those is relevant to your problem, please post some more details.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, updating VS2017 to 15.9.7 recently solved the issue above.
I am not sure what exactly change the issues.